# VLOOKUP to return multiple matches

Tags: vba, excel

I want to ask if there's a way/formula/vba to return multiple values when using vlookup? For example, I vlookup a data and when that data has multiple values to return, it will return the other values. Thanks.

Comment: Not with VLOOKUP I think, but you can do using an array formula.

Comment: Did you simply search the forum or Google the question before asking it here. Do some research on your part first.

Answer (score 0):

For something as generic as this, just use Google.

```
Step #1)  www.google.com
Step #2)  get your answer in less time than it takes you to post here.
```

Return MULTIPLE corresponding values for ONE Lookup Value

The Excel VLOOKUP Function searches for a value (ie. Lookup_value) in the first column of a table array and returns a value in the same row from another column in the table array. In case of multiple occurrences of the Lookup value, the function searches the first occurrence of the Lookup value, and returns the corresponding value in the same row from another column.

In case you want to return multiple corresponding values, for the one Lookup value which has multiple occurrences, we show how it can be done using INDEX, SMALL, IF & ROW excel functions, as follows.

Consider the table array ("A2:B8"), in which you want to lookup the value "Apples" in column A which has multiple occurrences, and return all corresponding values in column B.

Enter the lookup value "Apples" in cell A11. In cell B11, enter below formula, as an array formula (CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER), and copy it downward in the same column B, in 7 rows (ie. number of times as the number of records in the table array "A2:B8". Multiple corresponding values (of the lookup value "Apples") will get copied vertically, starting from cell B11 till B17. Refer Table 1.

[image]

=INDEX($B$2:$B$8, SMALL(IF($A$11=$A$2:$A$8, ROW($A$2:$A$8)-ROW($A$2)+1), ROW(1:1)))

http://www.globaliconnect.com/excel/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=119:vlookup-multiple-values-return-multiple-corresponding-values-for-one-lookup-value&catid=77&Itemid=473