# Excel lookup function taking only first cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup, lookup

I have a personals & holiday table. I want to transfer data to another table. But a personal (emre) has two holiday date. Lookup function taking only first data.

[image: main table]

[image: transfer table]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45139452/vlookup-to-return-multiple-matches

Comment: VLOOKUP doesn't return multiple matches.

Comment: To get the last match with unsorted data you'd need: `=LOOKUP(2;1/(Sayfa1!A:A=F5);Sayfa1!B:B)`, where you'd change LOOKUP to ARA

Comment: Have you ever heard of the concept of a screenshot? Windows 10 has the Snipping tool and Snip & Sketch. No need to photograph your screen.

Comment: This is a computer with no possibility of access to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it please? You should enter Ctrl + Shift + Enter to activate the array formula.

```
 =INDEX(Sayfa1!$B$2:$B$6,MATCH(TRUE,EXACT(A2,Sayfa1!$A$2:$A$6),0))
```

Useful Link:
https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2699-excel-vlookup-find-first-2nd-match.html

If it is too complicated for you research xlookup.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/xlookup-function-b7fd680e-6d10-43e6-84f9-88eae8bf5929

Comment: Thank you but when i push ctrl+shift+enter İTS giving error about formula. Why?

Comment: @E.YILDIRIM Replace commas with semicolon in formula.